# How to do conditional formating an Excel VBA macro?

Tags: vba

[vba](/questions/tagged/vba)
I have used the below code to insert conditional formatting in an excel cell..

```
range("d" & rowno).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="= RC > 7"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535 'Yellow
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

The above works fine by comparing the grater than value defined which is "7"...
But if i pass variable "lhigh" in which value is stored  and the same im passing it in the formaula it does not works.
e.g;
    `lhigh=7`

```
range("d" & rowno).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="= RC > lhigh"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535 'Yellow
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Please let me know how we can than calculate greater than check if we pass variable instead of direct integer value

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
Formula1:="= RC > " & lhigh
```

i.e. you need to do a string concatenation using the `&` operator.

`"= RC > " & lhigh` will then evaluate as `"= RC > 7"`.

Answer (score 2):

If I name a cell "Arc" and another to "lhigh" then the following sub works for me in Excel 2007

```
Sub test()

Dim foo As Range

Set foo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")

With foo.FormatConditions _
        .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=Arc>lhigh")

    With .Font
        .Bold = True
        .ColorIndex = 4
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

this will set conditional formatting on cell C3 which will kick in when the value in Arc > lhigh.

Perhaps you should simplify your code to something basic like this and then add the extra complexity. I'm guessing that your problem lies in another part of your code.